# How to open Gazelle Orange c7+ chain case?

Tags: chain

I would like to open it because I feel a touch while pedaling and gear changes are not smooth. Is there any video or manual to show how to open chain case?

[image: gazelle c7]

Comment: Added stock photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another model in a video on YouTube, i would image the removal process is similar. It appears to take a little prying, then a couple screws and that's about it. i would inspect the chain cover closer and see if there are any obvious tabs or seams that separate or if there are any visible screws from the inside (through the wheel)

Here is the link:

[Gazelle Chain Case Removal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roc0buQEjzk)

Comment: That's superb. I edited in a direct link to the video. I also deleted my answer. Thanks for sleuthing this.